# Copy a pandas.series to another

Tags: pandas

I have two pandas series as below:

```
a = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
b = pd.Series(['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'])
```

and I want to copy/replace a to b. namely, b= [1,2,3,4,5].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
b = a.copy()
```

you can verify that both series `a` and `b` are equal with:

```
pd.testing.assert_series_equal(a, b)
```